# Iterating Over An Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration

I have an array and filled its values like that:

```
$('#list input:checked').each(function() {
  deleteRecordIdsStr.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

I use that for my array:

```
deleteRecordIdsStr = deleteRecordIdsStr.join("-");
```

So I have an array like that. Let's accept that I pushed 10, 20, 30 to it at first and after that I made join.

How can I iterate over that array and get 10, 20 and 30 again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ids = deleteRecordIdsStr.split("-");
```

split is a String method that creates an array.

and the iteration will be:

```
for (var i = 0, l = ids.length; i <l; i++){

  //something with ids[i]
}
```

Comment: i agree and changed the example

Comment: Could you remove the second form (for...in)?  It’s a bad example; for..in should be used to loop over the keys of an object, not to loop through the elements of an array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" method is to use a `for`loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = deleteRecordIdsStr.length; i < len; i++) {
  alert(deleteRecordIdsStr[i]);
}
```

But jQuery also provides an `each` method for arrays (and array-like objects):

```
$.each(deleteRecordIdsStr, function(item, index) {
   alert(item);
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example usage(for ex. alerting items at list?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery each function to easy iterate through them.

```
$.each(deleteRecordIdsStr.split('-'), function() {
     // this = 10, 20, 30 etc.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @Raynos In my opinion it gets cleaner and since we're using jQuery there is no problem (see tags). But of course it's the same as as a for loop. It's a question of taste I guess.

Comment: I just see little reason to abstract away a `for` loop on an `Array`. Admittedly it's a valid style choice. It just feels very unnecessary. Especially when he cares about order, you shouldn't use an orderless each loop.

Comment: @Raynos - you are missing the point of down voting. According to its page, down voting is used `Whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect, vote it down!` You already admitted it is a style issue. Calm down with the down votes.

Comment: @Jeff I did realise I was being harsh afterwards but the vote is locked.