# Looping over a some hard coded data

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In several places, I have loops over a pre-defined set of values.

My current code is:

```
for (var period in {'today':true,'yesterday':true,'this week':true,'last week':true,'this month':true,'last month':true}) {
  ...    
}
```

It works, but is there a prettier way of doing this?

(`period` needs to be the *values*, not the index, otherwise I would use an array.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating Over An Array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167323/iterating-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, since it is specifically about literal values, which prevent (or at least complicate) the use of the old standard `for (i in varname) { item=varname[i];...}` idiom.

Comment: No, it's not a dup, I want period to successively contain the values 'today', 'yesterday', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming you don't need to worry about older Javascript engines (like IE<=8):

```
['today','yesterday','this week','last week',
 'this month','last month'].forEach(function(period) {
 ...
})
```

Comment: OP says: "(period needs to be the values, not the index, otherwise I would use an array.)"

Comment: And in the above code, `period` is the value, not the index.  The problem isn't the use of an array  *per se*; the problem is that `for varname in array` sets `varname` to the indexes rather than the values. `forEach` doesn't share that problem.

Comment: Yes, and in this case `period` is the value.

Comment: I suppose OP didn't phrase his question clearly then, as his example iterates the keys. I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: OP wants to iterate over the values `today`, `yesterday`, etc.  In his code he used an object with those as the keys because that's what `for`...`in` iterates over, but you can also use an array with `forEach`.  The results are identical; the details of key vs value only matter for explaining why he didn't use an array in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this in ES6 is:

```
for (var period of ['today', 'yesterday', 'this week', 'last week', 'this month', 'last month']) {
    // ...        
}
```

This is supported in firefox. If you js engine doesn't support it then use a ES6 transpiler or you'll need to fallback to older solutions.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `for of` loops.

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks, I've changed my tone a bit in the answer. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
var timePeriod = [ "today"
                 , "yesterday"
                 , "this week"
                 , "last week"
                 , "this month"
                 , "last month"
                 ];

for (var i in timePeriod) {
    with ({ period: timePeriod[i] }) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This has two advantages over @MarkReed's solution:

1. It works in all browsers.
2. It's faster because no function is ever called.

In addition, the use of the `with` statement prevents the infamous for loop clousure problem.

Comment: Your second point is incorrect. My solution calls no function.

Comment: I wasn't comparing my solution to yours.

Comment: You're saying "other solutions" which includes everything other than yours.

Comment: Interesting; I thought `with` was frowned-upon these days because of its scope-muckery.

Comment: @MarkReed It's only dangerous when you don't know what you are reading or writing. Otherwise it is very safe. It's also a nice way to make `let` (block-scoped) variables.